# Lenses with 7 and 8 CPU contacts

Tags: lens

There are lenses with 7 CPU contacts and 8 CPU contacts.Are they interchangeable? Can I use a lens with 7 CPU contacts on a body with 8 CPU contacts? And vice versa.

Comment: Are the lenses in the same mount?

Comment: Can you show us a picture of the lenses you are asking about?

Answer (score 3):

What is important is the mount. Even if the number of contacts is different, the lens will mount but the difference in contact may be that some features are not implemented on the lens which is possible on the camera, things like stabilization, power zoom, etc.